# What is the correct http methods for joining and leaving a chat

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

what is the right http methods to use for say leaving and joining a chat group, currently i am doing, they of course call database

```
chatRoom.route('/')
    .get(chat.getChats) // get all group chats
    .post(chat.createChat) // create new group chat
    .put(chat.joinChat) // add user to chat room members array from db
    .patch(chat.leaveChat); // remove user to chat room members array from db
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to create a separate route (or subroute) and then use POST to add a user to a group and DELETE to remove them. This way, the POST route creates the relationship between the user and the group, and the DELETE route gets rid of it. Maybe something like this:

- `GET /chats` - get all group chats
- `POST /chats` - create a new group chat
- `POST /chats/:id/members` - add a user to chat with specified id
- `DELETE /chats/:id/members` - remove a user from chat with specified id

This approach would work exceptionally well if you're using a relational database, since operations on `/chats/:id/members` would map directly to your junction table.